# Benefit of replacing null-checks with Optional#ifPresent

Tags: java, null, java-8, option-type, null-check

I've just moved from Java 7 to 8 and my code is littered with snippets like

```
if (myObj != null) {
    myObj.doSomething();
    myObj.doOtherThing();
}
```

I've noticed that null-checks are sometimes considered an anti-pattern and Java 8 promotes the use of Optional. Is there any benefit to having my code look like

```
Optional.ofNullable(myObj).ifPresent(obj -> {
    myObj.doSomething();
    myObj.doOtherThing();
});
```

Arguably, it makes the code harder to read.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/avoiding-null-statements

Comment: In many cases, null is a valid state for myObj, so it doesn't seem to be appropriate to use assertions.

Comment: The second snippet does not buy you anything. It replaces a simple if for a chain of calls and a lambda. Don't see the benefit

Comment: You are correct, in your example you should not use `Optional`. The linked question and its answers should give you an idea of when you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the advantages of `Optional` is that when you return an `Optional` from a method, it indicates that a method can return null. When returning a usual object it's not obvious whether one shoud do the null check of the returned value.